Observer for LTI system with linear inequality constraints for state
I have searched quite a bit about this topic but only found methods that consider equality constraints.
Consider LTI system
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}x&=Ax+Bu\\
y&=Cx+Du
\end{align}
$$
with inequality constraint for state $x$ as
$$
Fx\leq g
$$
where $A,C$ is observable, $A$ is stable, $F$ is square and $g$ a constant vector (the $\leq$ is meant to be applied element-wise).
Without the state constraint it is easy to design the state observer. But is it possible to design a state observer for this system which takes into account the inequality constraint? If yes, how?
I found some papers that handle equality constraints like Detectability and Observer Design for Linear Descriptor Systems (2014) by Gupta et al but I couldn't find anything useful for this problem.
Update: The system is forward invariant for the set $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\vert Fx\leq g\}$. We can also assume that initial conditions are within $X$, so $x\in X$ forever. This is ensured by the inputs $u$ which are bounded such that $x$ can not leave $X$.
The problem is matrix $B$ is not known very well, we have only a crude approximation. So the observer states might leave $X$ because we have error in the inputs. On the other hand we know $F$ and $g$ very well, so my hope is we can use this additional information somehow to "help" the observer.
At the moment I am not restricting the trajectories, so sometimes we see that the observer leaves $X$ which we know in the real system can not happen (so this is obviously bad).
There are two simple solutions I can think of:

Limit the state of the observer but "don't tell him", so internally the observer still uses the unlimited state.
Limit the state of the observer and "tell him", so use the limited state also for the feedback in the observer model.

Both methods are not optimal. The first is bad, because if the observer overshoots, it might take same time until it reaches the valid set $X$ again, while the real system is already there. The second is bad because the design process was done without the limitation and so we can even lose stability.
So I am looking for a better method.

Is that set defined by $Fx\le g$ forward invariant for your system? If not, are you restricting the trajectories to be on the boundary when they hit the boundary of the set? If so, how? Also, do you want an observer that satisfy the same constraints?

@KBS thanks for your questions, I updated my question.
